# SSIS: How to pause a task and re-start execution based on variable evaluation

Tags: c#, ssis

I am stuck on this one:

I am using a `For Loop task` to evaluate a variable containing the value from the `Record/Row Count` from a table.

I need to make the loop continue to execute the task below as long as the Variable is greater than zero.

*The steps are as follows:*

1. Evaluated the Variable, if value greater than 0 run Task.
2. Pause task for X seconds and re-evaluate the variable, if the variable is still greater
   than zero, then run the task again, pause again,
3. Continue to Pause and run until the variable evaluates to zero, then exit the loop.

*This is what I have but it's just a sketch:*

[image]

*Step 1: For loop container:*

[image]

*Step 2: Scripting Task:*

[image]

*Code:*

```
public void Main()
{
double sec = Convert.ToDouble(Dts.Variables["IntPauseExecution"].Value);
int ms = Convert.ToInt32(sec * 1000);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms);

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

*Step 3: Getting record Count:*

[image]

*And finally, getting the result set for the count:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have modified in the code section. Please take a look at the code below. Before that we should pass `@IntRowCount` variable to the script task as `Read/Write` as follows.

***My Overall Package look like***

[image]

***Script task editor:*** 
[image]

***Code:***

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        int sec = int.Parse(Dts.Variables["Timer"].Value.ToString());
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["IntRowCount"].Value.ToString());

        int ms = sec * 100;

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms);

        //Flag the IntRowCount variable to go out of the loop 
        if (row != 0)
        {
            Dts.Variables["IntRowCount"].Value = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Dts.Variables["IntRowCount"].Value = 1;
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response: But the task stops after the first execution even though the Count is not zero. How do I continue to pause and execute until the count is equals zero?

Comment: Have you edited the code as mentioned above? We need to set the IntRowCount back to 0 in script task to make it work. It is working for me.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming I am also changing the variables in the For Loop, right?

Comment: What is the row count in your table [which is called by SQL execute Task]?

Comment: There is no set set number, the table can contain any amount of rows/records. It can be 1000 or 500 or anything.

Comment: Ok, After seeing your control flow screenshot. You call the timer script and get the rowcount [So rowcount will be overwritten]. Can you please try to move your SQL task first and call your script task as shown by my screenshot. Hope it helps!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45614/discussion-between-unaverage-guy-and-gowdhaman008)